# No module named 'pymysql' error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I use `!pip3 install pymysql` to install pymysql, and it says : Requirement already satisfied: pymysql in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.0.2)
My pip version is latest, and I open the Jupiter notebook from terminal, how can I fix this problem?

I saw this from other post may help my problem: " also got this error recently when using Anaconda on a Mac machine.

Here is what I found:

After running python3 -m pip install PyMySql, pymysql module is under /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages
Anaconda wants this module to be under /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Therefore, after copying pymysql module to the designated path, it runs correctly."
But I don't know how to copy pymysql module to the designated path,

Comment: I use "import pymysql" in the jupyter notebook, and the error came from "import pymysql", and I already installed pymysql on anaconda

Comment: Case is important. Try importing this instead: `!pip3 install PyMySQL`.

Comment: @mechanical_meat，it gives me the same error, "!pip3 install PyMySQL
import pymysql"

Comment: Ok, I'm really not sure what's going on then sorry. That combination of things that has been done and tried doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Jupyter has its own Python installation.  You need to have Jupyter do the 'pip install'.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) whose [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684500/no-module-named-pymysql-error-in-jupyter-notebook/74063675#comment123173487_69684500)

> Jupyter has its own Python installation. You need to have Jupyter do the 'pip install'.

provided the answer: I typed 'pip install pymysql' in my Jupyter notebook, and it solved the problem!